# Submit button moves around - CSS HTML

Tags: html, css, forms, layout

I am creating a simple eCommerce application using rails. I have a form on each product page that allows the user to select a number of color variants for that product and then a simple add to cart button.

The problem is that, on two different pages, the button appears in two different places while the code is exactly the same.

Here is the first example, it only shows three variants, and the button appears under these variants, like it should

> [image]

The html to generate this is as follows (jsfiddle code example here http://jsfiddle.net/zYAVW/)

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://192.168.1.113:3000/orders/populate" method="post">    
<ul> # A bunch of styled list elements # </ul>
<br><br>
<button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

But on my other page, where I have around 85 list elements the button appears inline with the styled list elements, but uses the EXACT same code, there is no css styling for the button or form and I can't figure out anyway to make it stay under the list.

Here is the image of the second page

> [image]

(jsfiddle code example here http://jsfiddle.net/zBAMN/)

Does anyone know

1. why this is happening?
2. how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: try adding clear:both and display:inline-block on the button.

Comment: @intelis Doesn't do anything...

Comment: You are asking how to solve a CSS problem without posting any CSS. Try making an example on jsfiddle.net. http://jsfiddle.net/SAYuk/

Comment: @mrtsherman Here is the example of the first page http://jsfiddle.net/zYAVW/ and the second http://jsfiddle.net/zBAMN/, I reduced the colorbloc size on the second because my screen resolution was forcing the add button to a new row, if your monitor doesn't do that increase the width back to 150px

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zBAMN/2/ add overflow hidden to ul element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **overflow:hidden** on the `ul` element.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zBAMN/3/

Comment: @mrtsherman true. Also i should point out, that any code that would be outside the ul element, like dropdowns or so, won't be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear:both` to your first break.

```
<br style="clear:both;"><br><button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zBAMN/4/

It's important that you understand why this is happening. You chose to float your list elements left so that they sit in rows. You need to clear this float or the following elements won't resume the typicald document flow. You can explicitly clear the float by inserting an element with the `clear: both` style property.

See http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

As intelis pointed out, you can also add `overflow: hidden` to the parent element. This causes it to self clear once you close the parent tag.

See http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/